# Unity CSharp 2D texture

Tags: c#, image, unity-game-engine, game-engine

i am working on this game and the image is displayed fine in the game screen in Unity editor but when i build and run the image is blank.
Game view in unity: 
!([Game view in unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkcKc.png))
[the view after building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwBdo.jpg)
the texture source is the hard drive. 
**the image is not in the project folder and is not built**
Any suggestions?
Please note i am learning unity and CSharp(New user).

Button Code:

```
public Category category;
public TextMeshProUGUI text;
public RawImage image;
public bool isFilled = false;
public int directoryLineNumber;

public void UpdateButtonData()
{
    text.text = category.name;
    image.texture = category.GetARandomImage();
    //image.Rebuild(0);
    isFilled = true;
}
```

```
{
    public string name;
    public string text;
    public List<Item> items;
    private string _path;
    //some code here not related
public Texture2D GetARandomImage()
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(_path);
        FileSystemInfo[] images = dir.GetFileSystemInfos();
        int i = Random.Range(0, images.Length);
        if (images[i].ToString().Contains(".png"))
        {
            WWW wWW = new WWW(images[i].ToString());
            /* Wait !! */
            while (!wWW.isDone) { }
            return wWW.texture;
        }
        else return GetARandomImage();
    }
```

Comment: This is a common problem thant can come from many places. Try to remove all scenes from Build and add it back in.

Comment: Now i have tried to :
- remove and re attach the scene 
- uninstall and reinstall Unity
- add the texture from the editor ( it worked but the method is not good for the game )
 - i have used a different PC and it is the same 

please any suggestions i am happy to hear even if it is just restarting my pc Lol.

Comment: If using the texture from the editor worked, why not use it?

I assume it's due to performance issues. If that's the case, I've written to another user [how to proceed to get an app faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57827031/5675325)

Answer (score 0):

Hi All i have solved this issue by using`Textuer2d.LoadImage(wWW.bytes);` instead of `wWW.tetxure`.

And now i can use different images types like '.JPG' and '.JPEG'
The code now looks like this:

```
public Texture2D GetARandomImage()
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(_path);
    FileSystemInfo[] images = dir.GetFileSystemInfos();
    int i = Random.Range(0, images.Length);
    WWW wWW = new WWW(images[i].ToString());
    /* Wait !! */
    while (!wWW.isDone) { }
    Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(1, 1);
    tex.LoadImage(wWW.bytes);
    return tex;
}
```

Thanks @Tiago for your suggestions.